# C# anonymous method/block?

Tags: c#, syntax, event-handling, mono, anonymous-function

I cannot understand this piece of code what is the "ViewDissapearing"? And what about "add" and "remove" blocks?

```
public event EventHandler ViewDisappearing;

public event EventHandler ViewDissapearing {
    add {
        ViewDisappearing += value;
    }
    remove {
        ViewDisappearing -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add and Remove are standard property for an event. This will be called when you hook up event handlers for this event ViewDisappearing. The same lies inside WinForm class for say Click event.
Perhaps this should give you more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163533.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/8627sbea(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense, since ViewDissapearing is redundant (it's just another entry point to ViewDisapearing)

Answer (score 4):

This is done to provide two names for the same event. "ViewDissapearing" is how the event was previously wrongly named, and all existing code that subscribes to the "ViewDissapearing" event is instead rerouted to subscribe to the new correctly spelt "ViewDisappearing" event instead.

The `add { ... }` block is executed when someone calls `ViewDissapearing += ...`, which does nothing more than `ViewDisappearing += that same ...`. Similarly for the `remove { ... }` block and `-=`.

Comment: +1 for discerning what was likely the scenario the code was taken from.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair More than just likely, I Googled it and found [this](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/pull/104/files) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is to allow other code to attach to this event. This is the same idea as the Get / Set Property of a variable. For Events it is Add / Remove. As with Properties of variables, you can use the Variable directly, or you can use an Property. You usually use the Properrty if you want to add some custom code when adding a event.

Comment: Yes, the silly thing here is that both the event and its explicit Add7Remove are public (and DiSSappearing is awful)

Answer (score 0):

This is explicitly stating what is normally autogenerated by the compiler for an event in a class.